# Debug on symbian

Tags: symbian

i am using trk for phone debug

it is working properly for Helloworld project

but it is showing error for my project when i start project in phone debug mode

1)Load failed

2)TrkProtocolPlugin:failed to download specified file to target
(please verify that target path is writable)

if any body understand what problem i am facing plz help me out from this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would check:

- if the application has correct privileges assigned (along with appropriate certificate)
- if ID of the application is not in conflict with some other application on device
- if installation package does not contain problematic commands (e.g. copy commands to non-accessible directories)

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually install the application on the phone? That is the first test you must perform before even attempting to use TRK.

Also, can your application start, at least to the point of showing a panic? TRK cannot help you if the applications cannot even load its DLL dependencies due to for example Platform Security capability mismatch. TRK needs a process to attach too in order to do its job ...